# Netbeans GUI SQL query

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc

I have built a form in Netbeans that has the following elements

FromDateText - Which a user can populate
ToDateText - which a user can populate

I have a SQL query which is simply

```
select(sum(cast(quantity as float)) as 'totalbuys'
from orders
where menunum in ('211', '215') 
and reversalflag = 'n'
and orderdate between xxxxxx and xxxxx
```

Now the order date is what I need to link to the FromDateText and ToDateText fields (cannot work this out) and feel very foolish because of it!

The result of this query in this instance lets say it 100.1234. I wish to have populate in another text box within the GUI

TotalBuysText

which will be done with setText code (again I presume) I just cannot work out how to get all the dots to connect.

Comment: which DB you are using?

Comment: Parse the dates using `SimpleDateFormat` and use `PreparedStatement` together with `setDate()` (or `setTimestamp()` if you need the time). Check the Java tutorial for an introduction on JDBC prepared statements. Do ***not*** concatenate user input into a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If your DB is Oracle you need to use `TO_DATE` function:

```
..and orderdate between TO_DATE('2003/07/09', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and TO_DATE('2013/07/09', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Mysql:

```
 ..and orderdate between date(<your date>) and date(<your date>)
```

Comment: This will make the application wide open for SQL injection. It's better to use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: In terms of the application being wide open for SQL injection, the app is for use by about six people and the DB is IP range locked bandwidth server processing ability and the fact that no-one here understands enough to be able to really even use excel the risk is tiny...  May address at a later time but I just need a very quick and dirty solution in as short a time frame as possible.